# Producing an amalgamated list using linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a querable collection of objects.

Each object contains a list.

I want to produce a list containing each element from the lists of each object in the collection.

How can I do this using linq or otherwise?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To flatten a nested list, use `SelectMany`:

```
IEnumerable<ChildType> flattened = list.SelectMany(o => o.ChildList);
```